# How to Manipulate Array Indexed Values from Matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

Given a matrix

```
mat = matrix(round(runif(min=0,max=1,n=9*9)),ncol=9,nrow=9)
```

say you want all the values of 1 **using array indexing**

```
indx.1 = which(mat == 1, arr.ind=TRUE)
```

*How do you manipulate those index values within your matrix?*

The below doesn't accomplish what I am after:

```
result.i.dont.want = mat
result.i.dont.want[indx.1[,1],indx.1[,2]] = NA
```

because, as far as I can tell, R indexes over every combination of indx.1[,1], and indx.1[,2].

I know this is very easy if you use arr.ind=FALSE, however, I am curious for arr.ind=TRUE.  For example:

```
result.i.do.want = mat
result.i.do.want[which(mat == 1)] = NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking about matrix indexing. `indx.1` returned by `which` is a matrix of 2 columns; you can use it directly to address matrix elements. This is known as matrix indexing. So try `mat[index.1]`.

Also consider this toy example:

```
A <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)

A[1:2, 1:2]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    4
#[2,]    2    5

A[cbind(1:2, 1:2)]
# [1] 1 5
```